# Groovy - decoding Base64 Image String to File

Tags: image, groovy, base64, decode

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to decode and Image in base64 format to an actual file in Groovy.

The String in Base64 I understand is valid because I'm try it in an  tag and works as expected.

This is my code:

```
private generateImages(ThemeInfo theme){
        createThemeResourcesFolders("$resourcesPath/images/theme/$theme.name")
        generateImage(Base64.decodeBase64(theme.logo), theme, "logo.png")
        generateImage(Base64.decodeBase64(theme.favIcon), theme, "favicon.ico")
}

private generateImage(byte[] imageByteArray, ThemeInfo theme, String name){
        new File("$resourcesPath/images/theme/$theme.name/$name").withOutputStream {OutputStream stream ->
            stream.write(imageByteArray);
        }
}
```

I get no exception and the files are generated but wrong because it doesn't really show the images. Any idea of what it can be?

Thanks in advance!

PS: this is the string image in base64 if you want to check: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5944885/base64Image.html

Comment: what do you mean by "wrong"?  are they empty?  do they hold garbage data?  what does e.g. `file` say about the file?

Comment: Hi @cfrick ! What i mean by wrong is that the file is generated but is corrupted... so when you try to open with any image program is not render. Thanks!

Comment: when using your example and using code along the lines of `new File(..).withOutputStream{ it.write(Base64.decodeBase64(new File(...).text) }` this produces the proper image.  the error is most likely in your source material.  check the resulting files (their size, their actual content, use `file` to identify, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already found the problem. I was trying to encode the hole string, including

> data:image/png;base64,

In order to decode it properly i had to remove this. thats all!